# Batch creation of Gispoint inside anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm a newbie, I'm using anylogic when I encountered some problems I would like to data table (excel table) in more than one of the latitude and longitude coordinates in the GISmap rendering, I consulted some information only to find through the GISpoint manually add a single GISpoint operation, I would like to know how to batch add the GISpoint through the excel

I would like to know how to batch add GISpoint through the data table

Comment: Also, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many `GISPoint`s and other GIS elements as you like programmatically. There is a full example model and help article here: https://anylogic.help/markup/create-gis-network-by-code.html